# SQL Query:- Difference prices of same month with same year with different tables , if not just show zero

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two different tables, just need to subtract price between same month with same year, if no data just show zero for that particular month and year .Now, it just subtracting with row by row irrespective of month and year.

```
Table 1                     Table2
Price   tran_date           Price       post_date
60      2018-01-01  30          2018-01-15
40      2018-02-08  30          2018-02-02
50      2018-12-28  30          2018-11-01
40      2019-03-01  10          2019-01-08
80      2019-04-11  60          2019-04-29
                    40          2019-10-01

Expected Answer:
Sum(price).        Year
30          January 2018
10          February    2018
30          November 2018
50          December 2018
-10         January 2019
40          March 2019
20          April 2019.
40          October 2019

Actual Answer:
Sum(Price)      Year
30          January 2018
10          February 2018
10          December 2018
30          March 2019
20          April 2019
-40         October 2019
```

SQL Query for table1

```
Select sum(price) from table1 where date(tran_date) 
between ‘2018-01-01’ and ‘2019-12-31’ 
group by month(tran_date),year(tran_date)
```

SQL Query for table2

```
Select sum(price) from table2 where date(post_date) 
between ‘2018-01-01’ and ‘2019-12-31’ 
group by month(post_date),year(post_date)
```

It’s should not subtract from 1st row of table1 with 1st row of table2,it should subtract with same month with same year. If there is no data just show zero for that particular month and year.

Please do help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why is the expected answer for January 2019 not -10, and October 2019 not -40?

Comment: Those look like smart quotes !!!

Comment: @Nick Yes you are right.I just updated the expected answer.Please do help.

Comment: @Nits something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bf488d8c3dbe1787fe3d763697fdb4aa

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select year(dte), month(dte),
       greatest( sum(price), 0)
from ((select tran_date as dte, price from table1
      ) union all
      (select post_date, - price from table2
      )
     ) t
group by year(dte), month(dte);
```

It seems very strange to not subtract the values.  I suspect you might just want:

```
select year(dte), month(dte),
       sum(price)
from ((select tran_date as dte, price from table1
      ) union all
      (select post_date, - price from table2
      )
     ) t
group by year(dte), month(dte)
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. But i just need subtract the prices with two tables with same month and year.

Comment: @Nits . . . In that case, `-40` would seem to be correct.

Comment: From table2, post_date is there not tran_date. so you just cant group by tran_date.

Comment: @Nits . . . That is just a typo in the second subquery (getting the column name wrong).  I adjusted the SQL so the use of dates should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

seems you want the absolute difference, try add abs()

sample

```
select date_year, date_month,
       abs(sum(price))
from ((select date_year, date_month, price from 
    (values (60, '2018', '01'),  
        (40, '2018', '02'),  
        (50, '2018', '12'),  
        (40, '2019', '03'),  
        (80, '2019', '04')  ) table1 (price, date_year, date_month)
      ) union all
      (select date_year, date_month, - price from (
    values (30, '2018', '01'),
        (30, '2018', '02'),
        (30, '2018', '11'),
        (10, '2019', '01'),
        (60, '2019', '04'),
        (40, '2019', '10')
      ) table2 (price, date_year, date_month)
      )
     ) t
group by date_year, date_month
order by date_year, date_month
```

see the fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qVQYB2KXSTbJNEkSH1oGuG/0